# Windows Phone 7 - Receiving a call

Tags: api, windows-phone-7

I am developing an app in which I would like to **receive phone calls** on a Windows Phone 7. Could you let me know if there is **any API exposed** to do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to intercept an incoming call?  There is no API access to that.